# use forloop on outputbuffer in SSIS transformation

Tags: c#, ssis

in a normal SSIS transformation, you might see something like this:

```
         ResultBuffer.AddRow(); 
         ResultBuffer.ID = <<some data>>;
         ResultBuffer.CustomerName = <<some data>>;
```

is there anyway to run through ResultBuffer's list of fields in a forloop Or foreach loop? similar to:

```
ResultBuffer.AddRow();
for (int i = 0; i < ResultBuffer.count(); i++) {
       ResultBuffer[i] = <<some values>>[i];
}
```

thanks.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/toddmcdermid/2011/05/03/iterating-over-columns-in-the-ssis-script-component/

Comment: I think this talks about inputbuffer iteration, I need outputbuffer iteration.  but thanks.